# How do I compare a list of dictionaries for equality in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, fluent-assertions

I'm trying to compare 2 objects *expectedItems* and *resultItems* of type `IEnumerable<IDictionary<string, object>>` but haven't been able to do much with it.

Also, one dictionary is initialised in the code, and the other one is built from a JSON response from an external API. Since, JSON doesn't really care about the order of the properties within the object, a `SequenceEquals` is ruled out.

I do have two equal objects and all of these understated methods are failing,
First,

`CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expectedItems, resultItems)`

Second,

```
var expectedItems = entries.Select(e => e.Serialize()).ToList();
resultItems.Zip(expectedItems,(objects, dictionary) => 
objects.OrderBy(pair =>pair.Key).SequenceEqual(dictionary.OrderBy(pair => pair.Key)))
                                   .Should()
                                   .NotContain(false);
```

The objects (as far as I see) are equal.

[image]

Any thing that I can try, or anything that I am currently doing wrong?

**EDIT**

The API trims the tick count from the timestamp that's why the failure. **How can I trim the timestamp in the expectedItems dictionary and then compare? So, the collections have to be same and the comparison for timestamp needs to be overridden. Anyone?**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things to check:

1. Are the object implementing preperly the `Equals()` method? If not the equality just check for the reference, and since they are two different instance they appear to be different.
   Another option could be, since your object is representing a Timestamp, as I guess by the picture.
2. even if it properly implements Equals, are the objects the same even in term of the millisecond ( if existing ) portion?

Comment: Yes, I checked further and it's the InternalTicks count that gets trimmed in the round trip. Any idea how do I counter that?

Comment: so check if Equals is defined ( the pt 1 )

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you install [FluentAssertions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentAssertions) and do something like this?

`resultsItem.ShouldAllBeEquivalentTo(expectedItems);`

I don't know by heart how restrictive the DateTime comparison is, but you can easily [override](http://www.dennisdoomen.net/2012/09/asserting-object-graph-equivalence.html) the behavior for a particular property.

Comment: I have fluent assertions installed. Will check this method. Thanks!